# In batch script silent installation using Reboot=reallysuppress is not updating the files

Tags: batch-file, silent-installer

I am using batch Script for silent Installation to update the locked and in use files.Using silent installation reboots my system automatically after the update.But I wanna setup a custom reboot message box , So I used the REBOOT=ReallySuppress attribute. And I used a message box to popup the custom reboot message. This helps me avoid the auto-reboot of the system but it is not updating the files even after performing a manual reboot. 
Here is the script that I am using.

```
@echo off
title Installing Updates
msiexec /i "C:\Users\tparvathaneni\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\SetupProject1\SetupProject1\bin\Debug\SetupProject1.msi" /qn /REBOOT=ReallySuppress
echo updates installed 
echo msgbox "Restart your system to complete the installation." > "%temp%\popup.vbs"
wscript.exe "%temp%\popup.vbs"    
pause >NUL
shutdown.exe /r /t 000
```

Can someone give me a solution to get the files updated with manual reboot.

Answer (score 0):

did you try instead of /REBOOT=ReallySuppress the /norestart option?

Please also make a log file in the install cammand via /l option. Then read the log if really the installer reboots the computer.